# fread not working inside reactive file upload function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to finalize my UI but using fread function with Fileinput function is giving me an error. My aim is to read larger files >50 mb efficiently using reactive function as the output of input file needs to fed into other reactive function.

**My use case:** User will have option to upload two CSV files and on the main panel the user will get the comparison statistics of both the files. Initially I have using read.table with read.csv but the function was very slow even to load 10 mb of data
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinycssloaders)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=500*1024^2)

ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demo: Upload Large Dataset > 10 Mb"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Upload reference file',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  '.csv'
                )),
      
      #Upload Dataset 2
      fileInput('file2', 'Choose file to upload',
                accept = c(
                  'text/csv',
                  'text/comma-separated-values',
                  '.csv'
                )),
      uiOutput("selectfile")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dataset 1", box(
          style='width:950px;overflow-x: scroll; height:700px;overflow-y: scroll;',
          withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("tb1"),type = 6, color = "#0dc5c1"))),
        
        tabPanel("Dataset 2", id = "Dataset 2", box(
          style='width:950px;overflow-x: scroll; height:700px;overflow-y: scroll;',
          withSpinner(DT::dataTableOutput("tb2"),type = 6, color = "#0dc5c1")))
    )
    )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  
    dffile1<- reactive({
      # inFile <- input$file1
      df <- fread(input$file1$datapath, data.table = FALSE)
      df$LotbyDate_Value<- paste(df$Col1,', (' ,df$Col2, ')')
      df["primary_column"]<- toupper(df$primary_column)
      df
    })

    
    dffile2<- reactive({
      # inFile <- input$file2
      df <- fread(input$file2$datapath, data.table = FALSE)
      df$LotbyDate_Value<- paste(df$Col1,', (' ,df$Col2, ')')
      df["primary_column"]<- toupper(df$primary_column)
      df
      # df<- df[order(df$primary_column),]
    })

  output$tb1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dffile1()
  })
  output$tb2 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dffile2()
  })
})

#Run App
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Sample datasets:**

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/arianazmoudeh/airbnbopendata https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/nurudeenabdulsalaam/fitbit-fitness-tracker-data

**I am getting this error:**

```
Error in fread: input= must be a single character string containing a file name, a system command containing at least one space, a URL starting 'http[s]://', 'ftp[s]://' or 'file://', or, the input data itself containing at least one \n or \r
```

Are there any other package/method I can use? Can you please help me finding the solution for the problem?

Thanks,
Aman

Comment: What is the value of `input$file1$datapath` (and `input$file2$datapath`) when the `reactive` executes?  That would be good to know...

Comment: @Limey 

Value will be the input file. The user who will upload the file after running the application using the Browse feature. The value will be that file. 

I tried implementing it in an alternative way:
      file <- req(input$file1$datapath)
      df <- fread(input = file, data.table = FALSE)
But after executing the previous error got resolved but I have a new error which is:
Warning: Error in : vector memory exhausted (limit reached?) r shiny using fread
?
I also tried using Bindcache but now I am unable to upload any file.

Comment: @Limey

```
     dffile2<- reactive({
       file <- req(input$file1$datapath)
      df <- fread(input = file, data.table = FALSE)
      df$LotbyDate_Value<- paste(df$Col1,', (' ,df$Col2, ')')
      df["primary_column"]<- toupper(df$primary_column)
      df
      # df<- df[order(df$primary_column),]
    }) %>%
  bindCache(input$file1)

Should I use Bindcache in the first place to remove the cache that is utilizing the memory or How do I resolve this?
```

Comment: I know you *expect* the value of `input$file1$datapath` to be the name of the input file.  But *is* it really?  (Similarly for `input$file2$datapath`)...

Comment: Indeed, you need `req`. Did you try `fread` these files outside shiny? Is there a memory exhausted error?

Comment: Hi @Limey

Putting `input$file1` is also not working. I am not sure how to pass the values here?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I tried `fread` by prefeeding the datasets and it is working. I am not sure how to write the function in such a way that the code accepts fread and rshiny doesn't takes longer to display the datasets.